# Адаптация под мобильные устройства bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap4

Есть два слайда для слайдера, в каждом слайде находится 4 блока с информацией.
На десктопе показывает 4 блока, на планшете 2, а на мобильном всё идет в колонку, а не "прячется".
Я не могу понять, какой класс нужно задать чтобы на мобильном прятались определенные колонки. d-none d-xs-none d-шоя-только-не-пробовал-none не работает

На компьютере должно быть все 4 блока, на планшете 2 из 4 и на другом слайде остальные 2/4, на телефоне 1/4
3 часа не могу ничего придумать, просто перебираю классы ,прошу вас - помогите чем можете пожалуйста

Использую бс4

[image: Десктоп]
[image: Планшет]
[image: Телефон]

```html
<div class="carousel-item justify-content-center">
<div class="row">
<div class="features-item d-flex justify-content-center col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
</div>
<div class="features-item d-flex justify-content-center col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
</div>
<div class="features-item d-flex justify-content-center col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
</div>
<div class="features-item d-flex justify-content-center col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="carousel-item justify-content-center">
<div class="row">
<div class="features-item d-flex justify-content-center col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
</div>
<div class="features-item d-flex justify-content-center col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
</div>
<div class="features-item d-flex justify-content-center col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
</div>
<div class="features-item d-flex justify-content-center col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Вот таким путем решил -

```
<div class="features-item justify-content-center col-lg-3 d-lg-flex col-md-6 d-md-flex col-sm-12 d-flex">
```

Создал 4 слайда, и к каждому слайду добавил такие классы, показать - `col-sm-12 d-flex` для мобильного устройства / спрятать - `col-sm-12 d-none`

Comment: в [доках же есть примеры](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/) `.d-none .d-sm-block` (первая таблица на странице)

Comment: @teran я пробовал это писать, в таком случае всё едет, мне кажется это из-за d-flex, d-sm-block это для >568px; (прикрепил скрин) https://imgur.com/QjlZZWk